# ClassNotFoundException oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver only in servlet, using Eclipse and oracle

Tags: eclipse

The code below fails on the line: `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");` 
with the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

The two printlns print: `Wed_Jun_22_11:18:51_PDT_2005 false` This makes me think the class exists and can be found. Also this exact same class works in an a non-servlet application.

I have rebooted everything multiple times and regenerated the application/servlet multiple times. All values have been hard coded to make it simple and short.

I'm using: Eclipse JavaEE 1.4.2 Tomcat 7 jdk1.7 Oracle 11g R2 Windows 7 64bit

I have already added the jar files in web-inf. but it is still giving the following error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver`.

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to tell what exactly going wrong without looking into your application and tomcat server. But there are a couple of hints for your issue.

1. `NoClassDefFoundError` always makes me think that there is class collision rather than **missing jar file**. Be ware of the difference between `ClassNotFound` and `NoClassDefFoundError`
2. tomcat loads class in a different way as what normal java app does. Normally, the class loaders in a stand along java app will follow **delegate pattern**, which means the child class loader will always delegate the class loading job to its parent class loader. But tomcat does not exactly follow this. So it will load(find source file, read byte code and create a instace of class **Class**) by itself.

So check your tomcat lib as well as all the web apps under the tomcat and see if there are multiple version of **ojdbcXXX.jar**

Comment: i found it. :D
reload the odbc jar files.

Answer (score 0):

Go through C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\lib  path(this path may be differ ->based on where you pasted the Tomcat server )  then past ojdbc14.jar if its not contain.

Then restart the server in eclipse then run your app on server